# mod_rewrite usage

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have situation that I need to direct all request matching `http://mywebsite.com/portfolio/[anyname]` to `http://mywebsite.com/portfolio.php?username=[anyname]`. Can anybody help me write .htaccess file for that.

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can likely get away with a simple rule like:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule  ^portfolio/(\w+)$  portfolio.php?username=$1  [L]
```

If the usernames can contain anything else but letters, use `.+` instead of `\w+`

The other options are documented under http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html